# I can't install 'Package Control' in sublime text 3

Tags: installation, sublimetext3, package-control

I tried to install 'Package control' in sublime text 3, but I couldn't do it.

I copied python code from "https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3"

When I pasted the code to sublime text 3 console, the package was not installed.

```
">>> import urllib.request,os,hashlib; 
h = '6f4c264a24d933ce70df5dedcf1dcaee' + ebe013ee18cced0ef93d5f746d80ef60'; 
pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; 
ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); 
urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); 
by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); 
dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); 
print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by) 
286331"
```

The number, "286331" is the error(?) message.

After this error, I already tried manual method but I couldn't solve the problem.

I don't know how can I do next.

Comment: The manual method does not work for you? Are you sure you are doing it right?

Comment: Yes, I did. but...I did format the disk and reinstall windows, so I solved this problem. Thank you for your reply! :D